# How many times is to_date executed in where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following query, is the to_date function executed multiple times or just once?  This query is running long and I'm trying to find a way around it without asking for an index to be added.

```
select edi_stat_rsn_cd
, TSET_ID
, count(*) as count
from comt_po_msg
where TSET_ID in ('PSH','ORD','850','870')
and trunc(crt_ts) = to_date('03-06-2017','mm-dd-yyyy') --here
and LOC_TYP_CD in ('BOSS','STH')
group by edi_stat_rsn_cd, TSET_ID;
```

Comment: If you are using RDBMS with a decent optimizer it should treat it as a constant.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: The query is not running long due to `to_date('03-06-2017','mm-dd-yyyy')` but due to `trunc(crt_ts)`, see Gordon's answer to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query. This will avoid the `TRUNC()` function for every row,

```
SELECT EDI_STAT_RSN_CD
    , TSET_ID
    , COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM COMT_PO_MSG
WHERE TSET_ID IN ('PSH','ORD','850','870')
    --AND TRUNC(CRT_TS) = TO_DATE('03-06-2017','MM-DD-YYYY') --HERE
    AND TO_CHAR(CRT_TS, 'MM-DD-YYYY') = '03-06-2017'
    AND LOC_TYP_CD IN ('BOSS','STH')
GROUP BY EDI_STAT_RSN_CD
    , TSET_ID;
```

Comment: Calling `TO_CHAR()` instead of `TRUNC()` doesn't seem like a big win to me.  In addition, the question is about `TO_DATE()`.

Comment: In addition to Gordon's comment '03-06-2017' is a string not a date; you're relying on implicit conversion to avoid errors, which can change for every session that you use.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable optimizer should only call deterministic functions once on constants.  But why bother?  Instead, use the `date` keyword to include a date constant:

```
where TSET_ID in ('PSH', 'ORD', '850', '870') and
      trunc(crt_ts) = date '2017-03-06' and
      LOC_TYP_CD in ('BOSS', 'STH')
```

This has the additional advantage of allowing standard date formats.

The use of `trunc(crt_ts)` can prevent the optimizer from using an index -- which is a much bigger consideration than calling `to_date()`.  I would recommend:

```
where TSET_ID in ('PSH', 'ORD', '850', '870') and
      crt_ts >= date '2017-03-06' and
      crt_ts < '2017-03-07' and
      LOC_TYP_CD in ('BOSS', 'STH')
```

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, it should be treated static since you are using static value `to_date('03-06-2017','mm-dd-yyyy')` and your `to_date()` function doesn't depend on column value (or) not getting evaluated based on per record value